# ADF Oracle Service Cloud connector - correct endpoint

Tags: oracle, rest, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I'm trying to create a linked service by using the Oracle Service Cloud (Preview) connector to connect to my organisation's Oracle HCM instance. I'm generally following this guidance, using the copy data tool, which should be straightforward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle-service-cloud?tabs=data-factory

I have tried the following host names...

https://xxxx.xx.xxx.oraclecloud.com/

https://xxxx.xx.xxx.oraclecloud.com/hcmRestApi

https://xxxx.xx.xxx.oraclecloud.com/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/grades

https://xxxx.xx.xxx.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/grades

... but all of the generate the following error...

Error code 9603

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][OSvC] (20) Error while attempting to use REST API: Couldn't resolve host name
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][OSvC] (20) Error while attempting to use REST API: Couldn't resolve host name
Activity ID: 590c5007-ec6f-4729-9eb2-d05ef779dc0e.

I'm using a username and password that has been tested on Oracle, and have tried various combinations of using encrypted endpoints, host verification and peer verification as true or false.

I believe I'm using the correct endpoints, based on Oracle's guidance:

Oracle REST endpoints
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/22c/farws/rest-endpoints.html

I'm not sure what else to try to get this connector to work? Has anybody else got it to work, or perhaps noticed something I'm doing wrong with the host name?

Comment: What Integration Runtime do us use for connecting to oracle - Azure IR or Self Hosted IR?

Comment: I'm using an Azure IR

Comment: @DaarioNaharis did you every figure this out?

Comment: @MilesCole I had the same issue, same error. Solution was to remove the url schema (https://) and trailing slash from the host name. Then the connection was successful.